# Phalcon PhpFramework - Routing

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

Have an application using phalcon and I wants routes URLs like this :

http://localhost/my-website/admin/cat  -> use the "cat" controller and not the "admin" controller

Have done this and its works

```
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router();

    $router->add(
    "/admin/cat",
    array(
        "controller" => "cat",
        "action"     => "index"
    )
);
```

but  how to route things like :

http://localhost/my-website/admin/cat/updatecat/22  -> use the "cat" controller with action "updatecat" and parameter "22" and not the "admin" controller

Comment: is "admin" the module name..?

Comment: I dont know : its a simple application with this structure :                     my-website/
    app/
        controllers/                                                                                          
        models/
        views/
    public/
        css/
        img/
        js/   thanks for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Phalcon PHP custom route

This is how you do a custom route like yours:

```
$router->add(
"/admin/cat/([0-9]+)",
array(
    "controller" => "cat",
    "action"     => "index",
    "id"     => 1
));
```

You pickup the param in the controller like this:

```
$id = $this->dispatcher->getParam('id');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Was realy helpfull !